# SSH server - Get pid of sshd process forwarding port #N

Tags: linux, ssh, server, pid, ssh-tunnel

I'm running a server (Ubuntu Server 14.04) which allows the clients to make a ssh tunnel from their device (Raspberry Pi) so they can access their web server from the internet (as a mean to traverse NATs). I can get a list of processes owned by the user (which is the same for all the devices) using `ps -u username` (this user only runs sshd to forward ports), but I can't filter those processes by the port they're forwarding. So the question is, how can I get the pid of the sshd that is forwarding port #N?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `lsof` command since everything is a file on linux.

Something like `lsof -Pan -i | grep :PORT` will get you what you ask. It has an output like this when i run it for port 80 on my machine:

```
Command    PID     USER     FD  TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE  NAME
nginx      1104     root    6u  IPv4  23348      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1105 www-data    6u  IPv4  23348      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1106 www-data    6u  IPv4  23348      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1107 www-data    6u  IPv4  23348      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1108 www-data    6u  IPv4  23348      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

More on `lsof` can be found [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/lsof.htm)

Comment: Works great!! I can do `sudo lsof -Pan -i4 -c sshd -u domopro | grep :<clientPort> | awk {'print$2'}` and get only the PID, just what I need to automate the process. Thanks ;)